# Powershell parse key or value in json file

Tags: json, powershell

I have a Json file like below:

```
{
   "DevParametersList": {
      "PowerBIWorkspaceID": "062caXXXXXXXXXca3308a3b",
      "DatasetID": "f23a6b3d-d8fXXXXXXXa0a53c67"
   },
   "SITParametersValue": {
      "PowerBIWorkspaceID": "062cad8e-XXXXX8a3b",
      "DatasetID": "f23a6b3dXXXXa53c67"
   },
   "UATParametersValue": {
      "PowerBIWorkspaceID": "062cad8XXXX8a3b",
      "DatasetID": "f23a6b3d-d8XXXe5a0a53c67"
   },
   "ProdParametersValue": {
      "PowerBIWorkspaceID": "062cad8e-aXXX8a3b",
      "DatasetID": "f23a6b3XXXa8e5a0a53c67"
   }
}
```

Now, I want to get the **key and its vlaue** one by one under the tab **DevParametersList**, so that I could loop each of them.

How can achieve this?

My current Json file is:

```
$WorkflowListPath = "$(FilePath)\ParametersChangeList.json"
$jsonObj = (Get-Content $WorkflowListPath | ConvertFrom-Json).DevParametersList
$test = $jsonObj.keys

Write-Host "The test keys is:$test
```

But the result is null, the because the value of `$jsonObj` should be the json file, but I do not know to do continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the hidden `psobject` memberset to enumerate the properties of an object:

```
$jsonObj.psobject.Properties |ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Found a property named '$($_.Name)' with value '$($_.Value)'"
}
```